# Opencart - Options disabled when quantity 0

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have a code, but it does not work properly. When the `quantity` is `0` and `Subtract Stock` is specified as `Yes`, the option(s) disappear.

The option(s) remains only when `Subtract Stock` is specified as `No`.

Code:

In `catalog/controller/product/product.php`

**First:**

Replace: `if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {`

OG: `if ($option_value['subtract']) {`

**Second:**

After: `$option_value['name'],`

Add: `'quantity' => $option_value['quantity'],`

In `catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl`

Replace:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
```

OG:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" <?php if ($option_value['quantity'] == 0) { ?> disabled <?php } ?> />
```

Comment: How is it possible to subtract quantity of that option when it is out of stock?

Comment: @RadhikaMayani, I need to make so that "disabled" was applied to selectors of an option remains visible in any cases and regardless of which position is the switch in "Subtract Stock".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In catalog/controller/product/product.php

remove: 
    `if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {` and the closing bracket `}` a couple lines further down.

Now,
add: 
    `'quantity' => $option_value['quantity'],`

after: 
    `$product_option_value_data[] = array(`

In product.tpl 
    `<input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" <?php if ($option_value['quantity'] == 0) { echo 'disabled'; } ?> />`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made. Explain how it differs from the code in the question since there is no obvious difference.

Comment: Radhika Mayani, unfortunately this does not solve the problem. It is necessary to make the column "Subtract Stock" ignored. https://s6.postimg.org/713dq5hw1/Screenshot-2018-3-29_Products.png

Comment: to ignore "subtract stock" you need to remove
    `if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {`

from controller product.php .

Remove `if ($option_value['subtract']) {`

Comment: @RadhikaMayani, thank you for your desire to help me, but you can not understand me :(

Please read again my first post. If possible, you can repeat at your test store and you will see my problem and my request for help.

It is necessary to make so sure that when the quantity of the product is zero, but the option should not disappear.

Comment: @VeroN What I understood is that when quantity is 0,your option should be displayed but it is disabled to access. Am I right?

Comment: @VeroN Please check this. http://www.templatemaniacs.com/opc/FabDemo1/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=60

Comment: @RadhikaMayani, yes you are right. But the option should work. When buyers make orders the quantity should decrease. And when the number of options reaches zero, the option should not disappear and be visible in the storefront.

Comment: @VeroN Please check again above provided link when this is the scenario in admin side. http://www.templatemaniacs.com/opc/issue1.png

Comment: @RadhikaMayani, yes, need such a scenario. Tell please how did you do that?

Comment: In catalog/controller/product/product.php

remove:
`if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {`

add:
`'quantity'       => $option_value['quantity'],`

after:
`$product_option_value_data[] = array(
   `

In product.tpl

`<input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" <?php if ($option_value['quantity'] == 0) { echo 'disabled'; } ?> />`

Comment: @RadhikaMayani, If completely delete the line `if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {`, then an error will appear. You can edit your post with an answer to keep indenting and formatting the text.

Comment: @VeroN did you delete closing if loop bracket? '}"

Comment: @RadhikaMayani, yes, the problem was in "}". It seems now works as it should. Thank you very much for your help. The decision was close, but I did not see it. With your help, everything turned out. Have a nice day, friend. Regards.